# Как использовать Font в старых Android?

Tags: java, android, android-resources, android-o

Слышал что появилось новое в Android. Спустя тысячелетие. Google додумался дописать пару функций, чтобы шрифты можно было использовать из папки font.

Но беда в том, что эта штука не работает на предыдущих версиях Android. Работает от версии API 26 тобишь от 8 андроида. А что делать со старыми?

Comment: Использовать библиотеку поддержки - https://developer.android.com/preview/features/fonts-in-xml.html#using-support-lib

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Да как и со всем новым, что появляется для Android. (спасибо поддержке обратной совместимости)

> The Support Library 26.0 Beta provides support to the Fonts in XML
> feature on devices running Android API version 14 and higher.

## UPD#1 Как включить поддержку?

```
android {
  compileSdkVersion 26
  buildToolsVersion '26.0.0'

  defaultConfig {
    targetSdkVersion 26
  }
  ...
}

dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0'
}

// REQUIRED: Google's new Maven repo is required for the latest
// support library that is compatible with Android O
repositories {
    maven {
        url 'https://maven.google.com'
        // Alternative URL is 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/'
    }
}
```

Comment: А как подключить Support library 26.0?

Comment: @EraNewGames смотрите UPD#1

Comment: Подключил. Все сделал. Итоге при запуске никакой замены шрифта не происходит. Чо за фигня то....

Comment: @EraNewGames видать что-то не так делаете...

Comment: compileSdkVersion 26, должне быть или 25 пойдет?

Comment: Кстати это работает в Android stable. Или надо качать Canary?

Comment: @работает в stable. оставьте compileSdkVersion 26